# JS Open print dialog page to print a pdf file

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, dialog

I need to print a pdf file. The file names are listed from a database loop that contains the filenames of files within a folder. I have a script that can directly send to the printer, but I want to open the dialogue page instead. Depending on the file, I may only want certain pages printed.

`<button type="button" onclick="printJS({printable:'NEWPDF/<%=VAR2%>.pdf', type:'pdf', showModal:true})">`

Also using `<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script> <script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.css"></script>`

How do I open the dialogue??

Thanks

Comment: Also using
`<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.css"></script> `

Comment: Does this answer your question: [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)?

Comment: No because I do jot wish to print the current page. I wish to print the page that is a variable that contains the link to the pdf file.

Comment: Why don't you just make a link that opens a new window to that pdf file and then brings up the print dialog instead of trying to do this the hard way?

Comment: Fair question. I want to be amle to scroll down the list and click on what I want to print, select pages from file to print, and print without leaving the page I was on. It may seem petty but it is how i want it and how the others in my family wish for it  to be.

Comment: You can do that with dynamically generated links that open the PDF in question in a separate window so that the original window never goes away.

Comment: Can you give an example??